# In Rails, how do I determine if two URLs are equal?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

If I have two URLs in Rails, (whether they be in string form or URI objects) what's the best way to determine if they are equal? It seems like a fairly simple problem, but I need the solution to work even if one of the URLs is relative and the other is absolute, or if one of the URLs has different parameters than the other.

I already looked at [What is the best way in Rails to determine if two (or more) given URLs (as strings or hash options) are equal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/126332/what-is-the-best-way-in-rails-to-determine-if-two-or-more-given-urls-as-strin) (and several other questions), but the question was pretty old and the suggested solution doesn't work the way I need it to.

Comment: So what's the way you want it? When should it return true? Just check for controller and action?

Comment: @AnthonyAlberto I guess my original question was asking for a more general solution that would take any two urls (even if they are referring to a page on an external site) and check whether they refer to the same page. Come to think of it though, just checking for the controller and action would actually work just fine for me.

Comment: But is it in the context of your app? Or you need to test any URL?

Comment: @AnthonyAlberto For my purposes it really only needs to be in the context of my app. So yes, checking the controller and action for the two URLs would work fine. Is there an easy way to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Provided you have url1 and url2 being some string containing a URL :

```
def is_same_controller_and_action?(url1, url2)
  hash_url1 = Rails.application.routes.recognize_path(url1)
  hash_url2 = Rails.application.routes.recognize_path(url2)

  [:controller, :action].each do |key|
    return false if hash_url1[key] != hash_url2[key]
  end

  return true
end
```

Comment: Great, that's just what I need! Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

**1) convert URL to [canonical form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_form)**

In my current project I am using [addressable](https://github.com/sporkmonger/addressable) gem in order to do that:

```
def to_canonical(url)
  uri = Addressable::URI.parse(url)
  uri.scheme = "http" if uri.scheme.blank?
  host = uri.host.sub(/\www\./, '') if uri.host.present?
  path = (uri.path.present? && uri.host.blank?) ? uri.path.sub(/\www\./, '') : uri.path
  uri.scheme.to_s + "://" + host.to_s + path.to_s
rescue Addressable::URI::InvalidURIError
  nil
rescue URI::Error
  nil
end
```

Example:

```
> to_canonical('www.example.com') => 'http://example.com'
> to_canonical('http://example.com') => 'http://example.com'
```

**2) compare your URLs:** `canonical_url1 == canonical_url2`

UPD:

- `Does it work with sub-domains?` - No. I mean, we cannot say that `translate.google.com` and `google.com` are equal. Of course, you can modify it depending on your needs.

Comment: will this work with sub-domains? How about also using [addressabler](https://github.com/flipsasser/addressabler) gem to check if subdomain is present, and force it to *www* if it isn't

Comment: That looks great, but the method you gave doesn't work with relative urls: `to_canonical('/test') => "http:///test"`

The addressable gem does seem very relevant to what I'm trying to do here however.

Comment: @stephenmurdoch I've updated my answer. As for the addressabler gem, it seems it is not very actively maintained.

Comment: @Ajedi32 If you need to compare internal URLs in your rails app, then solution provided by Anthony Alberto is good. In such a case, please update your question.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the [addressable](https://github.com/sporkmonger/addressable/tree/) gem and specifically the `normalize` method (and its [documentation](http://rubydoc.info/github/sporkmonger/addressable/Addressable/URI%3anormalize)), and the `heuristic_parse` method (and its [documentation](http://rubydoc.info/github/sporkmonger/addressable/Addressable/URI#heuristic_parse-class_method)). I've used it in the past and found it to be very robust.

Addressable even handles URLs with unicode characters in them:

```
uri = Addressable::URI.parse("http://www.詹姆斯.com/")
uri.normalize
#=> #<Addressable::URI:0xc9a4c8 URI:http://www.xn--8ws00zhy3a.com/>
```